# Getting the page ID when clicking a custom link field in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-api, custom-field

I am creating a new link field in Sitecore following this link: [Link for custom link field](http://sitecorecode.com/index.php/tag/xaml/)

I have successfully created one called modal link. Specifically I want to get all the modal components that are currently in the page. I need to get the page ID, so that I could get the modal component it has then list it in a combobox. Right now I'm facing a problem trying to get that ID.

My code is exactly the same as no. 6 on the link

```
public class GoogleEvent : Link
{
    // Sets the value.
    public void SetValue(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    // Gets the value.
    public string GetValue()
    {
        return Value;
    }
    // Handles the message.
    public override void HandleMessage(Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.Message message)
    {
        //Hopefully get page ID here then pass it

        base.HandleMessage(message);
        if (message["id"] != ID || String.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Name))
        {
            return;
        }
        switch (message.Name)
        {
            case "contentlink:GoogleEvent":
                var url = new UrlString(UIUtil.GetUri("control:GoogleTrackinglink"));

                //Add the page id in url here

                base.Insert(url.ToString());
                return;
        }
        if (Value.Length > 0)
        {
            SetModified();
        }
        Value = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

In code, getting the context item is not giving me what I need, so I'm aiming to get the url because on Experience Editor, the page id is stated there.

example image of the url with page id[image]

Another problem occurs when trying to get the url is, I'm getting the source of the iframe dialog instead of the page url.

I've tried `WebUtil.GetRequestUru`, `HttpContext.Current.Request`, etc. They all return the same url, which is from the iframe dialog.

If you have questions about the code, I'm just using the codes given on the link. Is there a way to pass the url before going in to code?

Comment: You need the item id on where the link has been click or the id within the dialog?

Comment: I need the item id on where the link component is placed in. Basically the page item Id.

Comment: From the code for the Dialog window, can't you get the item Id?

Answer (score 1):

If you have done all the configuration as per the shared link only then as per point 5, you must have added `contentlink:GoogleEvent(id=$Target)`.

I am not sure about custom control but the same syntax has been used to get context item in commands like delete.

Please check the value of `message["id"]`, it might be the same which you are looking for.